# What is the difference between sed and awk?

Tags: sed, awk

- What is the difference between awk
  and sed ?
- What kind of application are best use
  cases for sed and awk tools ?

Comment: A related QA on unix.stackexchange: [Is there a basic tutorial for grep, awk and sed?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/is-there-a-basic-tutorial-for-grep-awk-and-sed)

Comment: https://pediaa.com/difference-between-sed-and-awk/#sed%20vs%20awk%20%20-%20Comparison%20of%20Key%20Differences

Comment: Check out this question and its answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734615/combine-lines-with-matching-first-field. I believe you would get a feeling from it.

Answer (score 657, accepted):

`sed` is a stream editor. It works with streams of characters on a per-line basis. It has a primitive programming language that includes goto-style loops and simple conditionals (in addition to pattern matching and address matching). There are essentially only two "variables": pattern space and hold space. Readability of scripts can be difficult. Mathematical operations are extraordinarily awkward at best.

There are various versions of `sed` with different levels of support for command line options and language features.

`awk` is oriented toward delimited fields on a per-line basis. It has much more robust programming constructs including `if`/`else`, `while`, `do`/`while` and `for` (C-style and array iteration). There is complete support for variables and single-dimension associative arrays plus (IMO) kludgey multi-dimension arrays. Mathematical operations resemble those in C. It has `printf` and functions. The "K" in "AWK" stands for "**K**ernighan" as in "Kernighan and Ritchie" of the book "C Programming Language" fame (not to forget **A**ho and **W**einberger). One could conceivably write a detector of academic plagiarism using `awk`.

GNU `awk` (`gawk`) has numerous extensions, including true multidimensional arrays in the latest version. There are other variations of `awk` including `mawk` and `nawk`.

Both programs use regular expressions for selecting and processing text.

I would tend to use `sed` where there are patterns in the text. For example, you could replace all the negative numbers in some text that are in the form "minus-sign followed by a sequence of digits" (e.g. "-231.45") with the "accountant's brackets" form (e.g. "(231.45)") using this (which has room for improvement):

```
sed 's/-\([0-9.]\+\)/(\1)/g' inputfile
```

I would use `awk` when the text looks more like rows and columns or, as `awk` refers to them "records" and "fields". If I was going to do a similar operation as above, but only on the third field in a simple comma delimited file I might do something like:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN {OFS = ","} {gsub("-([0-9.]+)", "(" substr($3, 2) ")", $3); print}' inputfile
```

Of course those are just very simple examples that don't illustrate the full range of capabilities that each has to offer.

Comment: To see some examples of pushing the boundaries of `sed`: http://sed.sourceforge.net/#scripts

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - Am I at a disadvantage if I only learn awk ? Is awk far more commonly used than sed ?

Comment: @blasto: My recommendation is to learn both but with more emphasis on awk. Lots of the regular expression stuff applies to both (and other tools and languages). Use sed for simpler stuff and try to avoid the complex things. It's really cool that you can do loops and branches in sed, but the resulting command lines are complex and hard to read. The answer to your question really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson - What would be most useful to an ETL developer ? ETL or Extract Transform and Load is a data-warehousing term. Put crudely, the job involves EXTRACTION of data from different disparate sources (such as DB's, excel files, csv files etc), TRANSFORMATION of the same and then LOADING into a datawarehouse (DW) for analysis, finding patterns in data, or just historical records. eg. End use of a DW - Algorithms applied to a DW of a grocery store which has data from the past 10 years might reveal that people who tend to buy apples also buy oranges or something similar.

Comment: A link says - http://www.vectorsite.net/tsawk_1.html - "There are, however, things that Awk is not. It is not really well suited for extremely large, complicated tasks." 
Now, how "large" a task can awk handle ? How does sed compare in that respect ?

Comment: That is a blanket statement with insufficient qualifiers. However, there is a point at which Python or Perl should be used instead of AWK. There are tasks at which a compiled language would be better. I would use AWK for textual data that appears in rows and columns. AWK is pretty much limited to one or two dimensional arrays (Python and Perl support much more complex data structures by comparison) and has really no library support. Not that it can't be done, but there just really isn't any established...

Comment: library. OTOH, Python and Perl have vast core and 3rd part libs. Sed can handle quite large tasks within its capabilities and, although one could argue that it's Turing complete, it's not very well suited for algorithmic approaches.

Comment: Just an FYI for anyone stumbling across this on a mac, try "sed -E 's/-([0-9]+.[0-9]*)/(\1)/g'" for the first sed example

Comment: @Steam Your example sounds like typical use case of awk, for example you can have a look at this [cool article](http://freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/look_mum_no_database_thanks_to_awk/).

Comment: @jena While there may be something cool about that, it's awful in so many ways I stopped counting.

Comment: FYI, the example from @DanielSchmidt translates `Total losses were -1234.56 this month` into `Total losses were (1234.56) this month` for an answer to the "accountants brackets" mentioned in the answer.

Comment: The main differences between mine and Daniel Schmidt's are that he includes `-E` which Mac sed requires to enable extended regexes (and Gnu sed accepts, it also accepts `-r`) which allows the use of parens and some other regex chars to be used without escaping. And he uses an improperly unescaped dot which causes the regex to only match numbers which consist of two or more characters (perhaps including a.following space). If he had escaped the dec. point then the number would require one. My regex doesn't have this problem. Neither is completely robust, however, since no anchors are used.

Answer (score 156):

1) What is the difference between awk and sed ?

Both are tools that transform text. BUT awk can do more things besides just manipulating text. Its a programming language by itself with most of the things you learn in programming, like arrays, loops, if/else flow control etc  You can "program" in sed as well, but you won't want to maintain the code written in it.

2) What kind of application are best use cases for sed and awk tools ?

Conclusion: Use sed for very simple text parsing. Anything beyond that, awk is better. In fact, you can ditch sed altogether and just use awk. Since their functions overlap and awk can do more, just use awk. You will reduce your learning curve as well.

Comment: I find sed is much easier to learn though, so you need to account for that. As you learn to master awk, it might be useful to quickly learn sed to be able to use it faster for things you might not know how to do in awk yet.

Comment: Don't ditch `sed`, `'s/search/replace'` is way easier to type than `awk`'s syntax and is what you need most of the time.

Comment: Better to use a mixture.  For instance, if you are looking for a pattern in a huge file, use grep to find the line number, and then sed to edit the line. Otherwise, sed is going to be much slower to process the entire file.

Comment: If you're a craftsman, you learn how to use all your tools and you'll know which to use when. If you're just fixing stuff, a hammer and a screwdriver might just be all you need.

Answer (score 81):

Both tools are meant to work with text and there are tasks both tools can be used for.

For me the rule to separate them is: Use `sed` to automate tasks you would do otherwise in a text editor manually. That's why it is called stream *editor*. (You can use the same commands to edit text in vim). Use `awk` if you want to analyze text, meaning counting fields, calculate totals, extract and reorganize structures etc.

Also you should not forget about `grep`. Use `grep` if you only want to search/extract something in a text (file)