# Replacing all commas with spaces - S/R with a Unix Command?

Tags: unix, replace

I'm looking for a Unix command that will allow me to search/replace in a file - I need to replace all commas in a certain file with spaces. I need to do this in a script and I'm looking to avoid parsing/reading the file line by line. Is there a simple unix command that will allow me to do this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`sed 's/,/ /g' filename >resultfile`

Answer (score 7):

You can use awk, sed, vi, ex or even Perl, PHP etc ... depends what you are proficient with.

sed example:

```
sed -i 's/,/ /g' filename_here
```

Comment: I'm using vi, but I need to do it in a script. Thanks.

Comment: If you're a vi adept, consider the commandline `ex` version which allows the same commands: `%s/,/ /g` would work. You can do this in a script, too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [awk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), in case you also need to expand your command with some conditionals ([take a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1632565/7658051))

```
awk '{gsub(",", " "); print}' file_path > resultfile_path
```