# What tool to use for parsing text

Tags: parsing

lets get right into this topic.
So I have a output from an cydia app called "AutoTouch".

```
touchDown(2, 634.4, 471.3);
usleep(66685.62);
touchUp(2, 635.4, 470.3);
usleep(365600.04);
```

Now, as i already made some functions for me, i want to parse that into something like that:

```
tapp(634, 471);
usleep(365600);
```

What simple language would u reccomend i should use to do that? It should be easy, but also powerful (like compare numbers and such hardcore stuff ^^) and work on osx/linux.

Thanks for your help and i hope i used the word "parsing" correctly :)

Comment: I think the answer to your question is "Any", although it could also be "Try one".

Comment: I was about to suggest visual basic for its ease of use but thats a windows product, although I got it working within wine for linux.

Comment: @GolezTrol Ya, i could probably also do it with C++ but i want something simple and i am not in expert, i dont know where to start "trying".

Comment: @Mike Ok thx, maybe someone has a another idea with osx/linux, but i will take your suggestion into consideration. :)

Answer (score -1):

On linux/unix/osx, [sed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) is your friend. You'll find a [nice sed tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) on grymoire. Depending on your specific needs, you could use [awk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) as an alternative. There is also [nice awk tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) on grymoire.

The answer to [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632113/what-is-the-difference-between-sed-and-awk) should help you choose between these two tools.