# SED replace each placeholder with variable lines in file II

Tags: file, variables, text, sed, replace

```
sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"
```

Works perfectly if "Var4" is at the end of the line, however if any text exists after it, the output is incorrect ?

Input.txt

```
TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Output.txt should look like this:

```
TextBox1.Value = "0000AAAA"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "0000BBBB"  Then
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Replace.txt

```
0000AAAA
0000BBBB
0000CCCC
```

Output.txt after using:

```
sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
0000AAAA
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If

TextBox1.Value = "Var4"  Then
0000BBBB
Else
TextBox1.Value = "- - - - - - -"
End If
```

Any Advice ?

Comment: Sorry Not working >>>>>> sed '/Var4.*/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\n\(.*\)/"\1"/}' > "output.txt"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/R` command of GNU `sed` can't be used here because there is no chance to use the values from replace.txt for processing. `/R` will write them to stdout immediately, not into the pattern space. That means that there is no access from any sed command to the content of replace.txt.

Described here for example: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-37

> the "r" [or R] command writes the file to the output stream. The file is not inserted into the pattern space, and therefore cannot be modified by any command.

---

**Solution**:

I would use `awk`. Like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{r[NR]=$0;next}/"Var4"/{sub(/Var4/,r[++i])}1' replace.txt input.txt
```

Explanation using a multiline version:

```
# True as long as we are reading the first file (replace.txt)
NR==FNR{
    r[NR]=$0 # Store replacement in an array r
    next     # Don't enter the blocks below
}

# When "Var4" is found
/"Var4"/{
    # replace Var4 by next element of r
    sub(/Var4/,r[++i])
}

1 # Print the line
```

---

Btw, even if it would work, the `/R` command is a GNU extension of `sed` and will not work in other versions of `sed`. The above `awk` script should work with any version of `awk`.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you
- What is the difference between sed & awk ?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632113/what-is-the-difference-between-sed-and-awk

Comment: With a little Tweak, this also works >>>>> sed '/Var4/R replace.txt' input.txt | sed '/Var4/{N;s/"Var4"\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/"\2"\1/}' > "output.txt"

Comment: yes, that should work but that would process in the input file twice which is not really efficient.

Comment: `/"Var4"/{ sub(/Var4/,r[++i]) }` will work with the OPs posted sample input data but not with other data (e.g. if a `&` appears in replace.txt or if `Var4` was `Var.4`). Personally I'd use `BEGIN{old="\"Var4\""; lgth=length(old)-2} ... s = index($0,"\"Var4\"") { $0 = substr($0,1,s) r[++i] substr($0,s+lgth) }` so the comparison and replacement are both literal string operations and so will work given any input.

Comment: Good point. I wanted to keep the script simple here on SO. A production solution should also include a check for the length of replace.txt. I mean it should fail when there are no more indexes in `r`