# Find filenames matching lines in a text file

Tags: unix

I have a text file as follows:

```
orthogroup1
orthogroup4
...
```

And I have a directory with text files as follows:

```
orthogroup1.faa.reconciled
orthogroup2.faa.reconciled
orthogroup3.faa.reconciled
orthogroup4.faa.reconciled
...
```

I want to use the text file to get the corresponding filenames in my directory.

The result should be something like:

```
orthogroup1.faa.reconciled
orthogroup4.faa.reconciled
```

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

The `-f` option of `grep` allows you to take patterns from a file. Use that on the output of `find` to filter out the list:

```
find /path/to/dir -type f | grep -f /path/to/patterns
```

Comment: Ah dang ok, I thought that's what you wanted.

Comment: Well, if you have control over the list of files to match, you could edit (or generate) it so that each line ends in `\.`, like `orthogroup1\.` and so on. That will match up to the first dot separator.

Comment: do you know how can I now copy the output of the command above to a new/different directory? thank you very much :)

Comment: If you mean the textual list, just use the redirect operator: `find /path/to/dir -type f | grep -f /path/to/patterns > /path/to/list/of/matches`

Comment: I was aiming to move the actual files, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

Can you define what you mean by "get the filenames in my directory"? What next step do you have in mind for them?

Seems like you probably want to use something like `sed` or `awk`, although the latter is probably overkill. See [What is the difference between sed and awk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632113/what-is-the-difference-between-sed-and-awk) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
suffix='.faa.reconciled'
for line in $(cat file.txt); do
    echo $line$suffix
done
```

Example:

```
$ cat file.txt
orthogroup1
orthogroup4

$ ls -l ortho*
orthogroup4.faa.reconciled
orthogroup3.faa.reconciled
orthogroup2.faa.reconciled
orthogroup1.faa.reconciled

$ suffix='.faa.reconciled'; for line in $(cat file.txt); do echo $line$suffix; done
orthogroup1.faa.reconciled
orthogroup4.faa.reconciled
```