# matching and reformatting poorly typed filenames

Tags: regex, bash, rename, filenames

I have a large number of filenames that have been poorly formatted, which I would like to clean up.  The idea is to reformat the names so that they are more sensible.

Here are some examples:

```
01harpharm_3.1.aiff 1
01harpmute_2.6.aiff 1
01harpmute_2.6.aiff 2
01harpmute_2.6.aiff 3
01harpmute_2.6.aiff 4
```

If we look at the last example, the goal would be to rewrite

`01harpmute_2.6.aiff 4` as `01harpmute_2.6.4.aiff`.

I would like to use bash for this, either via a script (for loop), find, rename, or a combination thereof.
Would anyone have opinions on how to best tackle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following once. Following will only print the rename commands on screen, you could run 1 command from it and if you are happy with results then you could run my 2nd code.

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
  echo "$file" | 
  awk '
    BEGIN{ s1="\"" }
    { val=$0; sub(/^\.\//,""); sub(/\.aiff/,"."$2"&",$1)
      print "mv " s1 val s1 OFS $1
    }'
done
```

OR in case you want to put condition and check if file name has space or not so put an additional condition in `awk` command it will skip files which are not having space in their names.

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
  echo "$file" | 
  awk '
    BEGIN{ s1="\"" }
    NF==2{ val=$0; sub(/^\.\//,""); sub(/\.aiff/,"."$2"&",$1)
      print "mv " s1 val s1 OFS $1
    }'
done
```

---

---

Run following only after you have tested above code successfully please.

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
  echo "$file" | 
  awk '
    BEGIN{ s1="\"" }
    { val=$0; sub(/^\.\//,""); sub(/\.aiff/,"."$2"&",$1)
      print "mv " s1 val s1 OFS $1
    }' | sh
done
```

Comment: This works a treat!  Thank you, @RavinderSingh13 - If I want to change the extension for a subset of the files, can I just alter `sub(/\.aiff/,"."$2"&",$1)` to be `sub(/\.newext/,"."$2"&",$1)` ?

Comment: @jml, Your welcome, yes you could give it a try should work. Also you could select this answer as a correct answer too, cheers.

Comment: absolutely - sorry for the delay; just got back to this project.

Comment: also curious if awk has any advantages over sed in a context like this... do you have an opinion?

Comment: @jml, Yes `sed` is older tech than `awk`. `awk` definitely have upper hand than `sed`, and with time it is evolving too, so you can learn it and it will help you through out your life trust me on that :)

Comment: I saw this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632113/what-is-the-difference-between-sed-and-awk

Comment: @jml, yeah nice thread :) thanks for sharing, keep it up :) cheers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203085/discussion-between-jml-and-ravindersingh13).