# making matches generic for extension text replacement

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I would like to make the following `bash` / `awk` script match a string (the string looks like a failed extension but is actually a red herring - the file extension is recognized by the system as a different file type) and replace it after formatting it.
I've tried the following and it works...

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
  echo "$file" | 
  awk '
    BEGIN{ s1="\"" }
        { val=$0; sub(/^\.\//,""); sub(/\.aiff/,"."$2"&",$1)
          print "mv " s1 val s1 OFS $1
        }'
done
```

...but only if I hardcode/bake the '.aiff' identifier into the match for `awk`.  In this case the output yields something like:

```
mv "./38.5_4.harp.aiff 1" 38.5_4.harp.1.aiff
mv "./25.3_6.harp.aiff 2" 25.3_6.harp.2.aiff
mv "./45.6_4.harp.aiff 1" 45.6_4.harp.1.aiff
mv "./04harpmute_3.1.aiff 1" 04harpmute_3.1.1.aiff
mv "./03harpmute_3.0.aiff 1" 03harpmute_3.0.1.aiff
mv "./01harpmute_2.6.aiff 2" 01harpmute_2.6.2.aiff
```

**What I would like to do now is somehow make a generic variable that can be updated so that I can choose what file extension is generated upon output.  Something like the following (this does not work currently):**

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
  echo "$file" | 
  awk '
    BEGIN{ s1="\"" }
        { val=$0; sub(/^\.\//,""); sub(/\.sd2/,"."$2"&",$1)
          print "mv " s1 val s1 OFS $1
        }'
done
```

Note my attempt to type 'sd2' does not function correctly, and is generally the wrong approach as `sd2` is not a variable that can be changed easily.  Here is some sample output:

```
mv "./38.5_4.harp.aiff 1" 38.5_4.harp.aiff
mv "./25.3_6.harp.aiff 2" 25.3_6.harp.aiff
mv "./45.6_4.harp.aiff 1" 45.6_4.harp.aiff
mv "./04harpmute_3.1.aiff 1" 04harpmute_3.1.aiff
mv "./03harpmute_3.0.aiff 1" 03harpmute_3.0.aiff
mv "./01harpmute_2.6.aiff 2" 01harpmute_2.6.aiff
```

The desired output would be:

```
mv "./38.5_4.harp.aiff 1" 38.5_4.harp.1.sd2
mv "./25.3_6.harp.aiff 2" 25.3_6.harp.2.sd2
mv "./45.6_4.harp.aiff 1" 45.6_4.harp.1.sd2
mv "./04harpmute_3.1.aiff 1" 04harpmute_3.1.1.sd2
mv "./03harpmute_3.0.aiff 1" 03harpmute_3.0.1.sd2
mv "./01harpmute_2.6.aiff 2" 01harpmute_2.6.2.sd2
```

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59004334/matching-and-reformatting-poorly-typed-filenames) but found that I need more information in order to make this script more generic.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT2:*** After OP mentioned to change format of files with a variable then try following.

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 2>/dev/null | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
   echo "$file" | 
   awk -v format=".sd" '
    BEGIN{
      s1="\""
    }
    {
      val=$1
      sub(/\.aiff/,format,val)
      print "mv " s1 $0 s1 OFS val
    }'
done
```

Output will be as follows.

```
mv "./38.5_4.harp.aiff 1" ./38.5_4.harp.sd
mv "./25.3_6.harp.aiff 2" ./25.3_6.harp.sd
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** When I run following code in system I get following output. About `cat << EOF > ....` commands that I am creating Input_files actually(you don't need these commands for you :) ).

```
cat << EOF > "38.5_4.harp.aiff 1"
test bla
EOF

cat << EOF > "25.3_6.harp.aiff 2"
test bla
EOF

find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 2>/dev/null | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
   echo "$file" | 
   awk '
    BEGIN{
      s1="\""
    }
    {
      print "mv " s1 $0 s1 OFS $1
    }'
done

mv "./25.3_6.harp.aiff 2" ./25.3_6.harp.aiff
mv "./38.5_4.harp.aiff 1" ./38.5_4.harp.aiff
```

---

---

Could you please try following.

```
find . -type f -name "*.aiff*" -print0 2>/dev/null | 
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
do
   echo "$file" | 
   awk '
    BEGIN{
      s1="\""
    }
    {
      print "mv " s1 $0 s1 OFS $1
    }'
done
```

Comment: No, this does not seem to work.  Did you test the code before posting?  Creating three files with similar names should be enough for a test...

Comment: @jml, yes I tested before posting and it looked ok to me

Comment: to me it looks like there is something critical left out like sub() or whatnot...  but I might be missing something.  Maybe you could explain the way it's supposed to be working?

Comment: @jml, Good morning, I created 2 dummy files with shown sample names and code generates same commands like your shown expected samples, kindly do lemme know in case of any queries here?

Comment: There might be some confusion here.  The desired output would be something like `01harpmute_2.6.2.sd2`

Comment: I also requested a way to make "sd2" into a variable name, so if you have any ideas there it would be appreciated.

Comment: By variable you mean to say you want to search for those format files right? If that variable defines which format files you need to search then we need NOT to do changes in `awk` we need to do changes at `find` command level. Lemme know on same.